# What are the limits of quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations

Classical mechanics fails to describes many effects in atomic and/or molecular scale (e.g. photoelectric effect, tunneling ionization, Compton effect, etc.).  My question is  what are the limits of the quantum theory? is there some phenomena at the atomic scale which are out of reach of the quantum theory?

Comment: with quantum theory do you mean just the first quantization?

Comment: This question asks for a potentially open-ended list of examples and without a clear criterion of what constitutes an answer (e.g. do classical scenarios which in principle could be described quantumly but in principle are computationally intractable count? does "quantum theory" include relativistic quantum mechanics, or quantum field theory?) Please narrow it down so that an adequate answer can be identified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most famous limitation of quantum theory is its failure to incorporate gravity. The two most established pillars of modern physics are quantum mechanics and general relativity. Quantum mechanics is broadly a model of how particles work and interact and general relativity is a model of how gravity works. There is currently no theory of "quantum gravity" (although there are plenty of candidates, for instance [Loop Quantum Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_quantum_gravity) and [String Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory)), the search for such a theory is a highly active area of research in physics and has been for the last century.